# SET failed on device wlp2s0 ; Operation not supported

Tags: linux-mint, wifi

I wanted to turn my card into the monitor mode, so I did:

```
ifconfig wlp2s0 down
iwconfig wlp2s0 mode monitor
```

And it showed me something like this:

```
Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :
SET failed on device wlp2s0 ; Operation not supported.
```

I really need to turn my card into this mode, I don't have the wlan0 interface, i don't even know why.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ip`, not `i.config`. It will be something like this:

`ip link set wlp2s0 down`

`ip link set dev wlp2s0 monitor on`

And also check wlp2s0:

`ip link | grep wlp2s0`

If it doesn't exist, find another interface with `ip link`. It is also possible that your Wi-Fi adapter does not support the monitor function.

Answer (score 0):

try wireshark without any changes just with "sudo".

Comment: wireshark? looked like they were trying to run ifconfig & iwconfig...?

Comment: I think they meant "if you run `wireshark` it will put your wifi card into monitor mode"